# How do I copy Gravity Form response to copy last response to row 1 of another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets that I am trying to get to interact with one another after a form response submitted to Google Sheets from a Gravity Form.  I am trying to use onChange() but nothing is happening.  This is a modified script based on one shared by Cooper in a question similar to this.  This is the script I am using:

```
function onChange(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheets = ["Responses"];
  if(sheets.includes(sh.getName())) {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Last Response");
    var tgt = tsh.getRange(1, 1, 1, 5);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 5).copyTo(tgt);
  }
}
```

I have an onChange() installable trigger set up.  There are two potential issues I have noticed.

1st)  Two changes occur with a Gravity Form submission.  The first change, as indicated in the logs when I was troubleshooting, is adding a new row.  The next change as recorded in the log is "OTHER".

2nd)  When I use this script and check the trigger execution, there is an error which reads "Cannot get properties of undefined (reading 'getSheet').

Maybe I am totally off-base with the script I am using, or the method I am using.  So I am reaching out here.

Here is what I would like to accomplish.

I have sheet "Form Responses" which accepts Gravity Forms submissions as seen below.

"Form Responses"
[image: Form Responses]

I would like the last response, based on the event, to populate Row 1 of the sheet "Last Response" as indicated below.

"Last Response"
[image: Last Response]

(Then, with this data, I can take the last response and move it to a calendar spreadsheet.  I already have an operating script for that, however. A lot happens on the calendar spreadsheet, so I would like to leave that aspect of the project intact.)

Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**:

I modified the script to run based on changeType.  (In fact, I think I found a couple of errors in the original.)

Here is the modified script:

```
function onAChange(e) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
          if(e.changeType=="OTHER" && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Responses") {
            var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Last Response");
            var tgt = tsh.getRange(1, 1, 1, 6);
            sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, getLastColumn()).copyTo(tgt);
          }
        }
```

Getting no errors now, but getting no results.  Two triggers are still firing.  Both show "Completed".  Apparently, I am not telling the spreadsheet to do what I think I am telling it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple errors in your code:

1. `sh` is not defined, but I am not sure if you meant to use `tsh`
2. You are using `getLastColumn()` as a function but you are not referencing any sheet first.
3. You are using `rowStart` but that is not a method for the `Range` object.

You can use the following script as a reference:

```js
function copyFormValues(e) {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = e.source;
  var cType = e.changeType;
  if(cType=="OTHER" && sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Responses")
  {
    var r = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Last Response").getRange(1,1,1,6)
    sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Responses").getRange(2,1,1,6).copyTo(r);
  }
}
```

In my sample code I set the range to `A1:B1` but you can change it as needed, or if you have a specific range that you would like to use you can let me know and I can update the answer.

Note that in order for you to be able to use the script you need to create an installable `onChange` trigger.

#### References:

- [onChange Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)
- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: The destination range would be A1:F1.  The source range, however, would be based on the input (unless I delete the row every time).  I would rather not.  So the source range would be the row where the new data appeared, Column A, the same row, through Column F.  Something like (row, 1, 1, 6).  So I would have to define row as the row where the change took place, I suppose?

Comment: I don't think I want to use getLastRow in case another form submission occurs and it grabs the wrong data.  So it needs to be the tied to the actual event.

Comment: Tried your current script and am still getting nothing.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your sample sheet where you are currently testing the script?

Comment: Let me make a sample.  Can't share the current one.

Comment: Here is the link.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gjov9yMpfsrbsldLo-Rsbr9-WLGR0YenOjZvj6ZVx48/edit?usp=sharing  This is what I am getting.  It is now performing as needed provided I delete the contents of the first row in "Last Response" sheet.  However, I need the latest input in "Responses" sheet to show up, not a set range.

Comment: Sorry.  I got sidetracked and just now realized that I had not actually shared the spreadsheet.  It is now public.

Comment: Doing further research, it would seem that we cannot access the range values of the event with the onChange trigger.  (Not sure if I worded that correctly.)   For now I am going with your script and deleting the input row and everything else is working as desired.  It is not exactly what I was looking for.  There may be some unintended consequences to doing it this way.  That remains to be seen.  If there is another way to get to the goal, feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @ScriptingNovice Sorry I was just recently checking the file. You are correct, you can not retrieve the range from the change, only the source sheet. I think I forgot to mention that specific limitation because I did not know if that would be relevant for your use case. At the moment I think this would be the only possible method to accomplish this so far. Maybe the only consequences that I can think of is if you do something on the spreadsheet that is considered an "Edit" for the trigger as it could create a false positive.

Comment: I don't think a false positive will be an issue because my subsequent script matches the value with values in my Calendar sheet.  If the range has no value, which it won't have because I delete the row every time with the script, then the script does not proceed.  At any rate, this was very informative to me as I have not used the onChange trigger before.  Thank you for your assistance in this.

Comment: The only issue with your script was that I had to change "EDIT" to "OTHER" since the logs indicated that as the change type.  Otherwise, while it does not do exactly what I had wanted due to the limitations of the onChange trigger, I am able to use it with the modifications that I have outlined.  If you wish to modify that part of the code, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @ScriptingNovice I edited the answer with the proposed changes. You are right since there are lots of limitations due to how the trigger works. I wish we could have more options to do something more specific as you need.